# converting array of object into array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist, type-conversion

I have an array of object data like the following structure:

```
var mydata=[
          {"category" :"phone","name":"Apple","model":"5s"},
          {"category" :"phone","name":"Moto","model":"g4"}
         ]
```

I want to convert this into an array of arrays like this structure:

```
var expextedData=[
    ["category","name","model"],
    ["phone","Apple","5s"],
    ["phone","Moto","g4"]
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to convert each object to it's values.

I'm using a hard coded array of keys instead of using Object#keys to extract them because [the order of an object properties is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/5157454).

```js
var mydata=[
  {"category" :"phone","name":"Apple","model":"5s"},
  {"category" :"phone","name":"Moto","model":"g4"}
];
 
var keys = ["category","name","model"];

var result = [keys].concat(mydata.map(function(obj) {
  return keys.reduce((arr, key) => {
    arr.push(obj[key]);

    return arr;
  }, [])
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get values in each object and add that to an array and keys from any one object also can be pushed. something like this:

```js
var mydata=[
      {"category" :"phone","name":"Apple","model":"5s"},
      {"category" :"phone","name":"Moto","model":"g4"}
     ]
var arr = [];

arr.push(Object.keys(mydata[0]));

mydata.forEach(function(ob){
arr.push(Object.values(ob));
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to get first element of all unique keys from object and then `map` and `Object.values` to get values.

```js
var mydata=[{"category" :"phone","name":"Apple","model":"5s"},{"category" :"phone","name":"Moto","model":"g4"}]

var result = [[...new Set([].concat(...mydata.map(Object.keys)))], ...mydata.map(Object.values)]
console.log(result)
```